# Binding table in MVC 4 after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an HTML able, which I bind by using the following Action in MVC controller:

```
  public ActionResult BindTable(int ? page)
            {
                int pageSize = 4;
                int pageNumber = 0;
                List<Users> _users = query.ToList();
                return View(_users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
            }
```

Below the table I have the following HTML:

```
<textarea class="form-control" style="resize:none;" rows="9" placeholder="Enter value here..." id="txtValue"></textarea>
        <br />
        <button style="float:right; width:100px;" type="button" onclick="CallFunction()" class="btn btn-primary">Update specific record</button>
```

The Javascript function responsible for calling the action is as following:

```
 function CallFunction() {
       if ($('#txtValue').val() !== '') {
           $.ajax({
               url: '/User/UpdateUser',
               type: 'POST',
               data: { txt: $('#txtValue').val() },
               success: function (data) {
                   $('#txtValue').val('');
                   alert('User updated!');

               },
               error: function (error) {
                   alert('Error: ' + error);

               }
           });
       }
```

And here is the Action responsible for updating the user:

```
public ActionResult UpdateUser(string txtValue)
        {
            var obj = db.Odsutnost.Find(Convert.ToInt32(1));
            if(obj!=null)
            {
                obj.Text= txtValue;
                obj.Changed = true;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("BindTable");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("BindTable");
        }
```

Everything works fine. But the table doesn't updates once the changes have been made ( it doesn't binds ?? )...

Can someone help me with this ???

P.S. It binds if I refresh the website.. But I want it to bind without refreshing the website...

I created a BIND function with Javascript, but it still doesn't binds:

```
function Bind() {
       $(document).ready(function () {
           var serviceURL = '/User/BindTable';
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: serviceURL,
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           });
       });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually updating the page after receiving the AJAX response.  This is your `success` function:

```
function (data) {
    $('#txtValue').val('');
    alert('User updated!');
}
```

So you empty an `input` and show an `alert`, but nowhere do you modify the table in any way.

Given that the `ActionResult` being returned is a redirect, JavaScript is likely to quietly ignore that.  If you return data, you can write JavaScript to update the HTML with the new data.  Or if you return a partial view (or even a page from which you can select specific content) then you can replace the table with the updated content from the server.

But basically you have to *do something* to update the content on the page.

---

**In response to your edit:**

You create a function:

```
function Bind() {
    //...
}
```

But you don't *call it* anywhere.  Maybe you mean to call it in the `success` callback?:

```
function (data) {
    $('#txtValue').val('');
    Bind();
    alert('User updated!');
}
```

Additionally, however, that function doesn't actually *do* anything.  For starters, all it does is set a document ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //...
});
```

But the document is already loaded.  That `ready` event isn't going to fire again.  So perhaps you meant to just run the code immediately instead of at that event?:

```
function Bind() {
    var serviceURL = '/User/BindTable';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: serviceURL,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    });
}
```

But even then, you're still back to the original problem... You don't *do anything* with the response.  This AJAX call doesn't even have a `success` callback, so nothing happens when it finishes.  I guess you meant to add one?:

```
function Bind() {
    var serviceURL = '/User/BindTable';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: serviceURL,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            // do something with the response here
        }
    });
}
```

What you do with the response is up to you.  For example, if the response is a completely new HTML table then you can replace the existing one with the new one:

```
$('#someParentElement').html(data);
```

Though since you're not passing any data or doing anything more than a simple GET request, you might as well simplify the whole thing to just a call to `.load()`.  Something like this:

```
$('#someParentElement').load('/User/BindTable');
```

(Basically just use this inside of your first `success` callback, so you don't need that whole `Bind()` function at all.)

That encapsulates the entire GET request of the second AJAX call you're making, as well as replaces the target element with the response from that request.  (With the added benefit that if the request contains *more* markup than you want to use in that element, you can add jQuery selectors directly to [the call to `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to filter down to just what you want.)

Comment: Hi, I've created a bind function that calls the BindTable action, but it still doesn't binds??

Comment: @perkes456: And where do you call that function?  Literally, your `success` callback has exactly two lines of code.  Neither of which modify the table in any way.  Since you don't have any code which updates the table, the table isn't being updated.

Comment: I've added the bind function here:

function (data) {
     Bind();
    $('#txtValue').val('');
    alert('User updated!');
}
but it still doesn't updates...

Comment: Any ideas on what it could be? :/

Comment: @perkes456: I've updated the answer.  The problem still remains that you're not actually doing anything with any responses from the server.  You need to write code which updates the page if you want the page to be updated.

Comment: And I add this: $('#someParentElement').html(data); in success function inside Bind function??

Comment: @perkes456: You would use that (or something like it) in the callback which has the `data` that you want to use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103644/discussion-between-perkes456-and-david).